# Plugin manager not working in netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: netbeans

On upgrading from netbeans 6.9 to 7.0.1, my plugins are not visible in the plugins manager. But more importantly, I am not even able to install new plugins, or watch the avaialble plugins. No plugins are displayed in the list as suggestions. However all my proxy settings are configured correctly & also netbeans is able to connect to internet & download maven stuff.

I tried to manually import the settings of 6.9 into 7.0.1 but no effect. How can I again make it work ?

Comment: Have you tried to start without to import any settings at all? Just close NetBeans and rename your .netbeans folder, then start it again.

Answer (score 45):

Netbeans 7 hides most plugins by default.

From **Tools** (Menu) -> **Plugins** (Menu) -> **Installed** (Tab), check the box that says **Show details** and you should see all of the plugins you have installed.

Under the **Settings** tab in the same dialog, make sure you have the following Update Centers installed:

- Certified Plugins - http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0.1/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz
- NetBeans Distribution - http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0.1/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz
- Plugin Portal - http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/7.0/catalog.xml.gz

..and make sure each of them is checked. If these are not present or not checked, you will not see anything in the list of **Available Plugins** (tab). Make sure you **Reload Catalog** on the **Available Plugins** tab after adding these.

Comment: @d.raev Did this work? If so why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: Also in Netbeans 8.1, installed through Ubuntu 16.10 package manager, the check marks on these 3 items were missing. After checking these, I could install plugins.

Comment: You may have `Settings` instead of `show details` and `Check for Updates` at `Updates` tab instead of `Reload Catalog` at `Available Plugins`.

Answer (score 24):

I am using Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.10

My answer is essentially the same as cbednarski, but I noticed there was a slight difference: there was not a **Show Details** box to check under the Installed (Tab).

From **Tools** (Menu) -> **Plugins** (Menu) -> **Settings** (Tab)

Make sure you have the following Update Centers installed:

```
Certified Plugins - http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0.1/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz
NetBeans Distribution - http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0.1/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz
Plugin Portal - http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/7.0/catalog.xml.gz
```

..and make sure each of them is checked. If these are not present or not checked, you will not see anything in the list of Available Plugins (tab). Make sure you Reload Catalog on the Available Plugins tab after adding these.

Comment: nice to see Linux People Here :D

Comment: Netbeans documentation should fix it e.g. https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html